# Xcode Simulator Loads App then turns Black

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

My app contains one storyboard that begins with a navigation controller and a view controller with two buttons on it that lead to two further navigation controllers.  I have set the main view controller as the initial one, and pointed the main interface and launch screen file to Main.storyboard.  The app builds fine, launches the simulator, shows the initial view controller for a second, then turns black.  At the moment, I do not have a usbc-ligntning cable to test this on my actual device, and am not familiar enough with Xcode to know what is going on.  The code is pretty much default:

**AppDelegate.swift:**

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {



    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        return true
    }

    // MARK: UISceneSession Lifecycle

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, configurationForConnecting connectingSceneSession: UISceneSession, options: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) -> UISceneConfiguration {
        // Called when a new scene session is being created.
        // Use this method to select a configuration to create the new scene with.
        return UISceneConfiguration(name: "Default Configuration", sessionRole: connectingSceneSession.role)
    }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didDiscardSceneSessions sceneSessions: Set<UISceneSession>) {
        // Called when the user discards a scene session.
        // If any sessions were discarded while the application was not running, this will be called shortly after application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions.
        // Use this method to release any resources that were specific to the discarded scenes, as they will not return.
    }

    // MARK: - Core Data stack

    lazy var persistentContainer: NSPersistentContainer = {
        /*
         The persistent container for the application. This implementation
         creates and returns a container, having loaded the store for the
         application to it. This property is optional since there are legitimate
         error conditions that could cause the creation of the store to fail.
        */
        let container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "Finance_App")
        container.loadPersistentStores(completionHandler: { (storeDescription, error) in
            if let error = error as NSError? {
                // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
                // fatalError() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.

                /*
                 Typical reasons for an error here include:
                 * The parent directory does not exist, cannot be created, or disallows writing.
                 * The persistent store is not accessible, due to permissions or data protection when the device is locked.
                 * The device is out of space.
                 * The store could not be migrated to the current model version.
                 Check the error message to determine what the actual problem was.
                 */
                fatalError("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
            }
        })
        return container
    }()

    // MARK: - Core Data Saving support

    func saveContext () {
        let context = persistentContainer.viewContext
        if context.hasChanges {
            do {
                try context.save()
            } catch {
                // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
                // fatalError() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
                let nserror = error as NSError
                fatalError("Unresolved error \(nserror), \(nserror.userInfo)")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**SceneDelegate.swift:**

```
import UIKit
import SwiftUI

class SceneDelegate: UIResponder, UIWindowSceneDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?

    func sceneDidDisconnect(_ scene: UIScene) {
        // Called as the scene is being released by the system.
        // This occurs shortly after the scene enters the background, or when its session is discarded.
        // Release any resources associated with this scene that can be re-created the next time the scene connects.
        // The scene may re-connect later, as its session was not neccessarily discarded (see `application:didDiscardSceneSessions` instead).
    }

    func sceneDidBecomeActive(_ scene: UIScene) {
        // Called when the scene has moved from an inactive state to an active state.
        // Use this method to restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) when the scene was inactive.
    }

    func sceneWillResignActive(_ scene: UIScene) {
        // Called when the scene will move from an active state to an inactive state.
        // This may occur due to temporary interruptions (ex. an incoming phone call).
    }

    func sceneWillEnterForeground(_ scene: UIScene) {
        // Called as the scene transitions from the background to the foreground.
        // Use this method to undo the changes made on entering the background.
    }

    func sceneDidEnterBackground(_ scene: UIScene) {
        // Called as the scene transitions from the foreground to the background.
        // Use this method to save data, release shared resources, and store enough scene-specific state information
        // to restore the scene back to its current state.

        // Save changes in the application's managed object context when the application transitions to the background.
        (UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate)?.saveContext()
    }


}
```

**And MainViewController.swift:**

```
import SwiftUI
import UIKit

class MainViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }


    /*
    // MARK: - Navigation

    // In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        // Get the new view controller using segue.destination.
        // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
    }
    */

}
```

As you can see, these are pretty much the defaults.  Running the true default Hello World app runs fine, so I do not believe this is a problem with simulator itself, but an error of my own creation somewhere in the code.  I am very new to Xcode, but not to programming in general, so naturally I jumped straight in and ran into problems.

Comment: I did nothing to Info.plist, but the console currently says:
2020-01-08 21:57:14.150389-0500 Finance App[1666:91149] XPC connection interrupted
Message from debugger: Terminated due to signal 15.

I'm not sure if that is relevant...

Comment: I may also be misunderstanding what you mean by the Console.  I was using it in playgrounds but this is a single view application

Comment: You selected SwiftUI project so first make UIView Not UIViewController and mention rootViewController in SceneDelegate so black screen not display in simulator, For Demo project you can also refere this code : https://www.appcoda.com/swiftui-form-ui/

Comment: @AnjaliShah Sharp eyes! well done

Comment: Thank you @matt , Please upvote my answer because recently many have this problem so it's can be helpful to others.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You selected `SwiftUI` project so first make `UIView` Not `UIViewController` and mention **rootViewController** in SceneDelegate so black screen not display in simulator,

For **Demo project** you can also refere this code : [Simple SwiftUI Example](http://appcoda.com/swiftui-form-ui)

Comment: I appreciate your answer, but could you be a little more specific?  I assume you mean that MainViewController.swift should define the class MainViewController: UIView, correct?  Should I do the same for subsequent view controllers?  Also, what do you mean by mention rootViewController?  Is this a variable, function, class?  How do I 'mention' something?

Answer (score -2):

Instead of using SwiftUI, I recreated the project using storyboards as the interface.  This solved the problem.